User settings for .NET 6 add-in/class library
In a .NET 6 class library project - how do you save and retrieve user settings?
I used to use the Properties.Settings methodology but that has been deprecated and I am struggling to find an alternative.
I have tried using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration - but this only supports reading values - not saving them - so thats a major problem.
